# Image cropping issue react-image-crop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, crop

I am using [**react-image-crop**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop#how-to-filter-rotate-and-annotate). When using the npm, I can pull the crop dotted lines from the corner but I need to crop it from the sides as well.
So it is possible to do so? Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question but does removing the `aspect` from `state` do the trick? This allows you to freely crop both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Can I use aspect and do this?

Comment: No, aspect ensures that you have a fixed aspect-ratio for the crop.

Comment: Just a small question, Can I make square in the centre https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-crop-demo-with-classes-ubj59?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Yes,  `crop` takes `x` and `y` attributes that allows you to adjust positioning.